# Xcode -" ld: framework not found" happening on a framework not included directly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, build, frameworks

A bit of story:
I created a framework called, Notifications, that allows our iOS applications to use one of our new backend service. I created the framework in Swift, and included it in our main application which is written in Obj-C. This was working great until one of my colleauges updated the main application to allow us use Swift in the main application.

I am now getting the following error:

```
ld: framework not found ISO8601 for architecture x86_64
```

This is a rather interesting error as the Notifications framework uses ISO8601, and it is included in the Notifications framework. The main application does not reference this framework at all.

Yes, I did check to make sure ISO8601 has has the x86_64 architecture, and all included frameworks, and the Notifications framework also has all the required architectures.

I looked at the build settings and they appear to be all in line with building the project as expected.

For me the only difference appears to be enabling Swift in the main app. I have cleaned, deleted derived data, and various build settings trying to get it working.

Any thoughts or ideas for fixes would be greatly appreciated.